# HibernateMapping & JAXB

Tags: jaxb, hibernate-mapping

Can I use same Pojo class for hibernateMapping and jaxb binding ?

For example, I have a username in my Pojo class and hibernate mapping bind username with a database field.

I would like to bind this username with xml properties and send that with soap.
Is it possible ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In fact [hyperjaxb3](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3) is an open source library that facilitates this process (there are likely others available).

If you want to do it by hand, all you need to do is put both JAXB and JPA (or whatever) annotations on your POJO.